# How to tell which iOS DeviceSupport folder a particular simulator uses?

Tags: ios, xcode

Per [this blog post](http://blog.neverthesamecolor.net/how-to-recover-disk-space-from-xcode/) it's safe to delete what's no longer needed in the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport` folder, but it's not clear to me which folder a particular iOS simulator maps to. Currently for iOS 11 I really only use the iOS 11.2 simulator, but as you see in the screenshot below there are 4 11.2 folders in `iOS DeviceSupport`. How can I tell which of those folders a particular simulator uses so I know to keep it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The DeviceSupport folders are not for simulator. Its images are in a different folder. These files are the debug symbols for each iOS version and you don't need them for anything else than debugging with that iOS version.

The simulator images are in CoreSimulator folder. You can get the UUID for each version by running this command:

```
xcrun instruments -s devices
```

Comment: ‍♂️I should have realized from the folder name it's referring to devices and not simulators, thanks!